# Defining Argument values with docopt

Tags: python, docopt

Im working on my first python "app" and after some advice from the participants on Stackoverflow. Ive decided to scrap what I had and start from scratch.

It seems to be parsing the arguments nicely for usage etc but im not sure how I am meant to assign the values to the args?

Do I have to create a nest of ifs? if so how do i do that for the args in docopt?

maybe like this?

```
if opt in ("-f", "--file"):
    FWORD = arg
```

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Basic domain bruteforcer

Usage:
  your_script.py (-f <file>) (-d <domain>) [-t 10] [-v]
  your_script.py -h | --help

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  -f --file     File to read potential Sub-domains from. (Required argument)
  -p --proxy    Proxy address and port. [default: http://127.0.0.1:8080] (Optional)
  -d --domain   Domain to bruteforce.(Required argument)
  -t --thread   Thread count. (Optional)
  -v --verbose  Turn debug on. (Optional)
"""
from docopt import docopt

def fread(FWORD, *args):
    flist = open(FWORD).readlines()
    return flist


if __name__ == "__main__":
        arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')
        print fread(fword)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Your arguments variable contains the argument and you look them up as you would in a dict. So if you want to call the fread function with the file argument your main would look like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1a')
    fread(arguments['<file>'])
```

If you call the script like this:

```
> python your_script.py -f myfiles/file.txt -d google.com
```

Then your arguments will look like this:

```
>>> print arguments
{'--domain': True,
 '--file': True,
 '--help': False,
 '--thread': False,
 '--verbose': False,
 '10': False,
 '<domain>': 'google.com',
 '<file>': 'myfiles/file.txt'}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. The file is provided on the commandline as an argument for -f --file. What im trying to work out is how do i pair the value to -f or to any of my options or arguments?

Comment: What do you mean by "pair the value" what value? The value given on the commandline as the -f parameter is in arguments['<file>'] and the -d argument is in arguments['<domain>'].

Comment: sorry im a noob so my descriptions arent very helpful. if i want to pass the value for -f to `def fread` how would i do that? how does the function know to use the -f value?

Comment: I think you might be a bit confused about how docopt works. I've tried to clarify a bit in my edit. Let me know if its still unclear.

Comment: thanks, yes I can print the arguments and see the txt file as the value but if i try print the return value from the function using `print fread(arguments['<file>'])` i get the following error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./attack2.py", line 32, in <module>
    print fread(arguments['<file>'])
KeyError: '<file>'
Im trying to work out how to pass the function the file

Comment: if i stick the file name in like this ` print fread('wordfile.txt')` it works as expected but i dont want to have to enter the filename into the code manually, thats the idea behind getting the file from commandline input of --file

Comment: Are you running the script from the command line and specifying the parameters like in my answer?

Comment: yes I am, but if i just print the arguments they look like this rather than as yours do  unknown@ubuntu:~$ ./attack2.py -f wordfile.txt -d google.com
{'--domain': 'google.com',
 '--file': 'wordfile.txt',
 '--help': False,
 '--thread': False,
 '--verbose': False,
 '10': False}
unknown@ubuntu:~$

Comment: i have it working now, i specified '--file' instead of <'file'>

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse) from the python standard library.

Comment: @tiggertoast I have looked at it and docopt looks much nicer and simpler. I was using `geptopt` originally.